# Regex String Replacement

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using VBA to filter records in an MS Access Database
I first need to clean the data in a particular column

An example item in this column would be `XXXZZZSTYS1234NCYORGxxxASD`

What i would like to do is if the string contains `STY` then remove subsequent characters until you reach `COYORGxxx` or `NCYORGxxx` or `CNYORGxxx` and then remove any characters after the `ORGxxx` if they exist

So in the example above it would be cleaned to `XXXZZZSTYNCYORGxxx`

It doesn't have to be VBA, I use notepad++ to test it

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following regex:

```
(.*?STY).*?((COY|NCY|CNY)ORGxxx).*
```

And replace it with:

```
$1$2
```

Where:

- $1 represents all characters until the first "STY"
- $2 represents COYORGxxx or NCYORGxxx or CNYORGxxx

Answer (score 1):

There you go.

```
(.*STY).*((CO|NC|CN)YORGxxx).*
```

- (.*STY) will catch every string of characters up to STY
- .* will skip characters until next catch
- ((CO|NC|CN)YORGxxx) will catch any string starting with CO, NC or CN followed by YORGxxx
- and the last .* is just here to ensure the match (not necessary in this specific example)

You then only need to replace with $1$2, $n representing the n-th catch of the regex.